# Sendmail error dsn=4.0.0 stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I am at a loss to what is causing my issue but when trying to send a mail from my server i see this in my `maillog`:

> Oct 16 12:11:19 MYSERVER sendmail[63109]: v9GBBJxD063109:
>   to=myemail@address.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00,
>   xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60384, relay=[127.0.0.1]
>   [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by
>   [127.0.0.1]

From the research i've done it was thought the issue was a global writable file in the `/etc/mail` folder but i dont see one in there.

Anyone know what else to look at?

Comment: Can the mail server resolve the external email address?

Comment: Im not sure how to check this but i have used multiple email addresses to test with all the same response in the logs

Comment: Just see if you can ping the address. So in your dummy example ping www.address.com

Comment: Yes it can ping the address

Comment: Every mail or some mails? What's reported in the log file during sendmail daemon startup/restart?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail in version 8.12 split into two different modes of operation, the mail transport agent (MTA) versus a mail submission program (MSP). Your logs likely indicate that the MSP is configured to deliver to the MTA running on `localhost` (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1). Since that MTA is not running, the mail fails to be delivered, though should be visible in the MSP mail queue:

```
$ sudo mailq -Ac
```

The exact MSP configuration can be confirmed by checking `submit.cf` which usually but not always bears that name and is usually present under `/etc/mail` or not depending on how your vendor presents the Sendmail install:

```
$ grep MTAHost /etc/mail/submit.cf
```

this should show the localhost name or IP address if my assumptions about your log message are correct.

Correcting the problem will either involve starting the MTA daemon (how varies by vendor and there may be other rakes to step on between here and a properly running daemon) or reconfiguring the MSP to instead deliver to some other MTA host (which requires fiddling around with usually a `submit.mc` file and some other concerns).

Comment: i have 127.0.0.1 in the submit.cf file for MTAHost. The server should be using a relay server which i have added to the sendmail.mc file. Should the MTA be this relay server?

Comment: You could do it either way, with a running MTA daemon, or `submit.cf` pointed to that other host(s) and some sort of cronjob for when those other host(s) are down.